# Translate C union to pascal variant record

Tags: c, pascal, records

Help a n00b out!

I'm writing bindings for a C library and I came across union declaration / variant record. I tried to make it work but with no luck.

**Original C code:**

```
struct _PurpleConversation
{
    PurpleConversationType type;  
    PurpleAccount *account;       
    char *name;                 
    char *title;
    gboolean logging;
    GList *logs;                
    union
    {
        PurpleConvIm   *im;
        PurpleConvChat *chat;
        void *misc;
    } u;
    PurpleConversationUiOps *ui_ops;
    void *ui_data;
    GHashTable *data;
    PurpleConnectionFlags features;
    GList *message_history;
};
```

**My translation:**

```
TPurpleConversation = record
    convtype : TPurpleConversationType; 
    account: PPurpleAccount;
    name : PChar;
    title: PChar;
    logging: Boolean32;
    logs: PGlist;
    ui_ops: TPurpleConversationUiOps;
    ui_data : Pointer;
    data: PGHashTable;                      
    features : TPurpleMessageFlags;
    message_history : PGList;         

    case u : integer of
    0:(
        im: PPurpleConversationIm;          
        chat: PPurpleConversationChat; 
        misc: Pointer;
    );
end;
```

**What I think is wrong with it:**

- First thing that is wrong with it is that the varaiant record is in a different location, but in Pascal it can only be placed in the end of the record.
- Variant record is falsely declared.

I asked some help from the #fpc channel and the two possible variants they pointed out was to make two records (one with only the variant record in it) and second was to use this case statement. The last option should be most compatible.

I have no previous experience with this kind of statement in Pascal so can somebody please explain how would this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read description with typical examples ( http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records )? If yes, could you add more details about the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work and crashes the host application and in my opinion the problem is that the record isn't what C library expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working with using Marco van de Voort's code and modifying it a little - maybe someone finds it helpful here.

```
{$packrecords C}
TPurpleConversation = record
    convtype : TPurpleConversationType; 
    account: PPurpleAccount;
    name : PChar;
    title: PChar;
    logging: GBoolean;
    logs: PGlist;

    case longint of
      0 : ( im : PPurpleConversationIm );
      1 : ( chat : PPurpleConversationChat );
      2 : ( misc : Pointer;
            ui_ops: TPurpleConversationUiOps;
            ui_data : Pointer;
            data: PGHashTable;                      
            features : TPurpleMessageFlags;
            message_history : PGList;         
        );
end;
```

**What was done:**

- Added the byte alignment directive {$packrecords C}.
- Removed the tag from variant record.

This allowed me to proceed and use that object a function parameter etc. and all was well. But there are other binding problems that just are not worth the effort so I dumped the FreePascal for this project and started pushing it in C.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The first is usually fixed by moving the fields after the union to one of the branches of the union, like in the example below, but that won't work here because the union is not anonymous.

Untested quick rearrangement:

```
TPurpleConversation = record
    convtype : TPurpleConversationType; 
    account: PPurpleAccount;
    name : PChar;
    title: PChar;
    logging: Boolean32;
    logs: PGlist;
    case u : integer of
    0:( im: PPurpleConversationIm;     );
    1: (chat: PPurpleConversationChat; );
    2: (   misc: Pointer;     
           ui_ops: TPurpleConversationUiOps;
           ui_data : Pointer;
           data: PGHashTable;                      
           features : TPurpleMessageFlags;
           message_history : PGList;         
    );
end;
```

Syntax can be learned from the docs: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu19.html

but this requires ui_ops to message_history to be prefixed by u.

Gboolean should be declared in the gtk/glib headers and of course packing could still mess this up.

Comment: Yes, I changed the Boolean type now - PGBoolean.